# Using Pico as GPIO extender

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, pi-pico

When the Pico became available I bought 2.
I installed MicroPython on the first and used for a few applications.

I though the Pico would make an excellent and inexpensive GPIO extender for the Pi, but this proved to be more difficult than I expected.

Recently Joan has written a Python module which allows control of the Pico via the microUSB link.
See [Pico as a computer peripheral](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=144&t=309323)

I successfully used this on my Pi4 but it proved to be unclear how to use this on macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a guide to using the Pico as a computer peripheral on Raspberry Pi OS and  macOS

## Prerequisites

The Python set up tools are needed during installation of the Python module.
pyserial is needed to run code.

These tools may be installed with the following commands.

Pi

```
sudo apt install python3-setuptools
python3 -m pip install --upgrade build
sudo apt install python3-serial
```

macOS

```
sudo pip3 install setuptools    # macOS
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade build
sudo pip3 install pyserial
```

---

## Download

The picod archive may be downloaded with the following commands.

Pi

```
wget http://abyz.me.uk/picod/picod.zip
unzip picod.zip
```

macOS
Download http://abyz.me.uk/picod/picod.zip using a browser
`unzip picod.zip`

---

## Copy the daemon to the Pico

Pi
Push and hold the BOOTSEL button on the Pico, then connect to your computer using a micro USB cable. Release BOOTSEL once the drive RPI-RP2 appears on your computer.

Drag and drop or copy the picod.uf2 file to the RPI-RP2 drive. The Raspberry Pi Pico will reboot and will now run the daemon.

If you have the annoying automount feature disabled or are using the Command line you will need to mount the Pico and copy the picod.uf2 file

macOS
I haven't done on macOS (it is only required once) but the Pi should be mounted under Volumes.

---

## Build Python modules

Enter the picod/PYTHON directory then build for the versions of Python you plan to use.

```
sudo python3 -m build
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

---

## To check the installation.

In order to get the code to run it is necessary to set an ENV variable see http://abyz.me.uk/picod/py_picod.html#picod.pico
(The default `/dev/ttyACM0` should work for Raspberry Pi OS)

`python3 -m serial.tools.list_ports -v Pico`
can be used to list Pico ports

Alternatively you can modify the Python modules to automatically locate the Pico.
Insert the following after `if transport == 'serial':` in  `class pico()` `__init__` (line 2737 in version 0.0.6.0)

```
            # Automatically locate Pico Milliways 2021-07-09
            device = os.getenv("PICO_DEVICE")   # Use PICO_DEVICE environment variable if available
            if device == None:                  # else search for Pico
                import serial.tools.list_ports as S
                try:
                    P=S.grep('Pico')
                    device=next(P).device
                except:
                    device='/dev/ttyACM0'        # finally default for Pi
```

Enter the picod/EXAMPLES/py_picod directory then

`python3 flash.py` # flash the Pico LED

`python3 callback.py` # test GPIO callbacks

`python3 adc.py` # test ADC reads